# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^nx_n$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

> Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^nx_n$ where
> $$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1+\sqrt{x_n^2+1}},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
> given $x_1=\sqrt{3}$

I tried finding the first few terms which go as follows:

$$\sqrt3,\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{2+\sqrt3},\cdots$$

This doesnt seem to follow a definite pattern, and Im not sure how to proceed. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: A somewhat nicer version: find $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n/2^n$ where $x_{n+1}=x_n+\sqrt{x_n^2+1}$ ;)

Comment: 2.094395102=2pi/3 is the answer.......   another note is that the limit Xn/Xn-1 approaches 1/2 as n tends to infinity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x_n = \tan\theta_n, \theta_n \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right),\forall n \ge 1\implies \tan(\theta_{n+1})=\dfrac{\tan(\theta_n)}{1+\sec\theta_n}=\dfrac{\sin(\theta_n)}{1+\cos(\theta_n)}=\tan(\frac{\theta_n}{2})\implies \theta_{n+1} = \dfrac{\theta_n}{2}, \theta_1=\dfrac{\pi}{3}. $ Can you take it from here?

Comment: A very clever manipulation!