# Proving arctan x as the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

First semester real analysis - I'm currently preparing for an exam and going through exercises in a book. I came across this problem where I can't seem to get off the ground at all.

The task is to prove that given the recursive sequence with $x_{0}=x$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}}{1+\sqrt{1+x_{n}^2}}$,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{n}x_{n}=\arctan x
$$

I've worked with recursive sequences a bit, but hadn't come across one with a variable starting point, and am a bit dumbstruck by having to look at the limit of the product of these two sequences where one is recursive and one is explicit.

Obviously, as $n$ goes to infinity, $2^{n}$ goes to infinity as well, while the only thing I managed to see wrt the recursive sequence so far is that

- The denominator is always greater than one and the numerator just the last term of the sequence, which leads me to conclude that we retain the original sign of $x$.
- The denominator is always larger than the numerator, meaning both that our value for each $x_n$ is less than one and that our sequence should be strictly monotonically approaching 0 from above or below depending on the sign of $x$.

Together, if I'm not mistaken, this means I can say that $0<|x_{n+1}|<|x_{n}|<1$ for all $n\geq1$ (which also means extreme values for $x$ are immediately reduced to lie within $]-1,1[$ if my conclusion is correct).

Of course, this leads me to assume that the sequence converges to $0$ - and given that the numerator is just $x_{n}$, when I substitute $0$ I of course get $0$ for the next term - so it is a fixed point.

Now I have an idea that the recursive sequences converges to $0$ while $2^{n}$ goes to infinity - but I haven't proved that, nor do I know how to bring these two together.

After writing down the first two terms of $x_{n}$, it quickly gets overwhelming with nested fractions, and not obvious how to potentially extract factors to look for an explicit formulation.

About the arctan, I only know that it is the inverse of tan, that it maps $\mathbb{R}$ into the interval $]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$, reaching $\pm\frac{\pi}{4}$ at $\pm1$ and that it approaches the limits of the interval asymptotically as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$ - but have no explicit formulation nor (as far as I can see) any other information that could help me.

What are specific strategies and tactics I can use when faced with such a problem setup - and what are some specific techniques to use in this particular case?

Comment: Hint: Let $x_n=\tan\theta_n$ and prove that $\theta_{n+1} = \frac{\theta_n}{2}$

Comment: I would say: relate $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}}{1+\sqrt{1+x_{n}^2}}$ to the addition formula or double-angle formula for tangents.

Comment: A [new virus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4033791) ;)

Comment: Thank you both - I did notice the similarity of the problem statement to the formula for $\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ - and I can see that it follows directly that setting $x_{n}=\tan{\theta_{n}}$ that $x_{n+1}$ will be $\tan{\frac{\theta_{n}}{2}}$ - but haven't been able to grasp how to incoroporate the $2^n$. ...Wait, since we're halving the angle each step, don't we undo that when we multiply by $2^n$... oooh. Now I just need to bridge the gap from tan to arctan - I'm afraid my mind isn't quite there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substitution $x_n = \tan\theta_n$

$$\tan\theta_{n+1} = \frac{\tan\theta_n}{1+\sec\theta_n} =\frac{\sin\theta_n}{\cos\theta_n+1}$$

$$=\frac{2\sin\frac{\theta_n}{2}\cos\frac{\theta_n}{2}}{2\cos^2\frac{\theta_n}{2}} = \tan\frac{\theta_n}{2} \implies \theta_{n+1} = \frac{\theta_n}{2}$$

Of course the last implication requires that the sequence is decreasing, monotonic, etc, which I will leave to you to prove. This means we have that

$$\theta_n = \frac{\arctan x}{2^n} \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\tan\frac{\arctan x}{2^n} = \arctan x$$

by the standard $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ limit or by series expansion.

Comment: That was very helpful - thank you. Those addition and halving formulas are really earning their keep here.